# VB.NET NHIBERNATE trouble to do a query with where clause in

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate

I've been looking all over the web to find the synxtax in VB to fix our problem.

We have been using our query like this when we need to search in a table a bunch of elements from a liste

```
Dim criteria As ICriteria = getSession().CreateCriteria(GetType(User))
criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("UserName", listofUsers.Distinct().ToList()))

Return CType(criteria.List(Of User)(), List(Of User))
```

It works but it does multiple select query which use a lot of ressources on our server. I'm looking for a way to fix that.

What I wish it would do is a simple query like this with a in clause

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USERNAME IN()
```

So if you guys have a way to this in VB.NET I would be most grateful.
Thank you

Comment: Well, there are IMO a few things you can do here, would almost go as far as saying this question is maybe a little out of scope for this site though, might be better off on the Software Engineering stack.

Comment: Aside, a couple thoughts.  It's possible that nhibernate is creating an un-optimised query, so you may have better results executing the query directly.  You may also have better luck returning the source data unfiltered from the DB(direct query or via NHibernate), then filter the result set in memory.  This you could maybe even do client side depending on your client of course and spread the processing load).  You could look a maybe a view in your DB which has a prepped dataset for you to filter.  Really heaps of options, you're going to have to figure what works in your context

Comment: I used Restrictions.in before and didn`t have this issue. Which queries is NHibernate creating?

Comment: @Firo If I pass a list of say 40 user he does 40 select * from USER where Username In('username1'); Until he has done the 40 users ... I really dont get why he does that.

Comment: i created an example console app to reproduce this and i can't. Either the function posted is called in a loop or there is a something with the driver class used. Could you check if the listofusers really contain all names and which driver are you using?

Comment: The code doesn't even look like it is possible https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/90d50c03475628d10336cbad368f071375056fef/src/NHibernate/Criterion/InExpression.cs#L91

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the LINQ approach instead?

```
Dim users =
   session
      .Query(Of User)()
      .Where(u => listofUsers.Distinct().Contains(u.UserName))
      .ToList();
```

I'm not sure how the NHibernate LINQ implementation will interpret the `Contains()` method. You will have to enable the SQL logging and see what kind of query it creates.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not sure I can use query sadly my version nhibernate quite old. It's a legacy system. I'll check if it can work with my version. Thank you.